# AJAX with Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I'm wanting to add some AJAX functionality to my Rails app, but have no idea where to start.

Here is the method that adds an item to an order:

```
def add_item_to_order
 if session[:order_id].nil?
   @order = Order.new #Don't create an order until there is an item to be added to it.
   @order.account_id = session[:user_id]
 else
   @order = Order.find(session[:order_id])
 end
 item = Item.find(params[:id])
 o_item = OrderItem.new
 o_item.item_id = item.id
 @order.order_items << o_item
 @order.total += item.sale_price
 @order.save
 session[:order_id] = @order.id
 redirect_to order_home_path
end
```

This is run when the user clicks:

```
<%= link_to item.name, add_item_to_order_path(item.id), :class => "fixed medium green button"%>
```

Can anyone give me any tips on how to get started, so the the item is added to the order via AJAX?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Great tutorial, did this myself: http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book Chapter 12 has some stuff on Ajax.

Important part is to set your link_to paramater `data-remote` to `true`:

```
<%= link_to item.name, add_item_to_order_path(item.id), 
    :class => "fixed medium green button" data-remote="true" method="post"%>
```

and in your controller you add

```
def add_item_to_order
    # other stuff
    # at the bottom:
    respond_to do |format|
          format.html { redirect_to order_home_path }
          format.js
        end

end
```

Then you'll need a .js.erb file to handle the format.js repsonse:

```
$("your_form").update("<%= escape_javascript(render('partial_page')) %>")
```

and a partial page file to hold the new data..

Comment: In the .js.erb file, what would be in place of "your_form"? The class of the button?

Comment: "your_form" is the ID of the div you used in your main html file to display the information you want updated by the ajax request. Could be a button where you want the text to change or a label to display new infos..

Comment: Book on which provided link by you have only 11 chapters.. :P

Answer (score 2):

1. Check on how to `render` javascript. In normal requests one would redirect to some action or render some view etc, for a `XHR` (`XmlHttpRequest`) you can `render` javascript through a server-sided js template that would be rendered. You will have to use the `LegacyPrototypeHelpers` provided for Rails-3 as the original helpers were only officially available for Rails-2.
2. A better approach(unobtrusive as Rails 3 prefers) will be to just send some data from the server. In the following example you have above I guess if you send item.id via a JSON object or some other format and then read it in the success callback of the place from where you made the `XMLHttpRequest`, then after getting the item.id you could create the HTML that the `link_to` creates and then append it to the DOM.